# How can you skip closing HTML tag with xmlTextReader?

Tags: html, c++, libxml2

I'm new to/learning libxml2. I need to take action whenever I find a specific HTML tag (in the simplified example below, that action is `std::cout`). My program below takes this action *both* when it encounters the opening and closing tags that match a specified string ("B"). However, I would like to only act upon finding the opening tag. How can this be done? I was unable to find/understand from the libxml2 documentation whether there is a way to distinguish between opening and closing tags, and I couldn't find a similar SO question.

**The Code**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libxml/xmlreader.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int ret;
  xmlTextReaderPtr r = xmlNewTextReaderFilename("foo.xml");

  if ( !r )
  {
    return -1;
  }

  ret = xmlTextReaderRead( r );

  while ( 1 == ret )
  {
    if ( std::string("B") == (const char*)xmlTextReaderConstName( r ) )
    {
      std::cout << "Found desired tag" << std::endl;
    }

    ret = xmlTextReaderRead( r );
  }

  if ( r )
  {
    xmlFreeTextReader( r );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Compiled Like This**:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-7)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -lxml2 -I/usr/include/libxml2 main.cpp
```

**Run With This XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<A version="02.00.00" priority="0" reliable="false">
 <B attr1="Type_B" attr2="usb" attr3="600">
  <C/>
  <D/>
 </B>
</A>
```

**Results In This Output**:

```
>./a.out 
Found desired tag
Found desired tag
```

Whereas I'd like "Found desired tag" to only be output once, i.e. only upon encountering the opening `<B>` HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader)](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlreader.html#xmlTextReaderNodeType) to determine what "type" of node the reader is currently on, [as defined here](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/pnetlib-doc/System/Xml/XmlNodeType.html) or in the xmlReaderTypes enum in xmlreader.h.

In this case, you'll want to differentiate between XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT and XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT (ignoring the latter).